# LibreOffice Base Macro run MySQL command ENCLOSED BY (and the enclosed are by qotation markes aka "

Tags: mysql, database, libreoffice

Im doing a macro in Libreoffice extract a txt file to mysql but all data has "double quotes".

in mysql terminal this command works fine.
`LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/Stock.txt' INTO TABLE StockXLS FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES;`

in macro like this it works `oStatement.execute("LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/Stock.txt' INTO TABLE StockXLS FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' IGNORE 1 LINES;")`

but if i add ENCLOSED BY '"' I get erro.
`oStatement.execute("LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/Stock.txt' INTO TABLE StockXLS FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES;")`

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

oStatement.execute("LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/Stock.txt' INTO TABLE StockXLS FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '" & """" & "' IGNORE 1 LINES;")